# When is it ok to call functions in SELECTs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some stored procedures that have a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE
    dbo.Users.DatePaidUpTo > GETDATE()
```

Is this ok? Would it be more efficient to this:

```
DECLARE @currentDate DateTime
SET @currentDate = GETDATE()

    ....

WHERE
    dbo.Users.DatePaidUpTo > @currentDate
```

If that is more efficient, how can I do something similar for views? As this syntax:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_Recommendations]
AS

DECLARE @currentDate DateTime
SET @currentDate = GETDATE()

SELECT
    ....
```

Is invalid.

Comment: Have you tried actually running these different variations and looking at the execution times and execution plans to see what the difference is?

Comment: @Pondlife I haven't. I was fairly certain that functions-in-selects was bad though. The first half of the question was mainly a lead up to "How do I do this with views?"

Comment: Table Valued Functions are pretty much "views that take parameters" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx Maybe that's an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can call a function outside of a query, it will minimise the risk that the function will prevent any pre-compilation that may occur, such as in views, because the function will be evaluated for every record.

IF the function is complex or time consuming, running it once beforehand may improve performance.

In your example, you would have the view without the function call, then evaluate the function in the SQL using the view, such as a stored procedure.

Comment: It's a bit annoying that it isn't possible to put variables in views. My view just does a `GROUP BY` on another table that contains one-many links (its to show how many recommendations a post has). I don't think there is an easy way to put the function call outside the view without changing lots of other stuff. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: This is to optimise the performance of views.  A view can be precompiled and indexed so that queries can take much less time.

Comment: Stored procedures allow business rules and functions etc. more readily.  Stored procedures can still have some compilation but cannot be indexed in the same way views can.

Answer (score 1):

You can call them where you like, if it is a field which will always return the same value such as `GETDATE()` then put it in a variable and limit the number of database calls.

Obviously if the result from the function was variable depending on the input into the function then keep this inside the select / where.

At the end of the day it will come down to execution time, if you are iterating over a set of 100 records then the performance difference between either method will be not worth worrying out. If it was over 100 million records then optimization would be a consideration.